# dart map - does not print all key-value paris added to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map declared like below inside a class

```
var testMap = new Map();
```

On the initState method I am writing couple key-value pairs to it

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    testMap['dn'] = 'test name1';
    testMap['ph'] = '4160000000';
    testMap['dn'] = 'test name2';
    testMap['ph'] = '7780000000';
  }
```

But when I print the values of testMap like below, what I get is just

```
print(testMap);

Result - {dn: test name2, ph: 7780000000}
```

Where did the first key-value pair go?

Comment: You have duplicate keys, so the later entries overwrote the older ones.

Comment: I am trying to have an output like the below { dn: test name1, ph:4160000000}, {dn: test name2, ph: 7780000000}

Comment: That would be a `List` of separate `Map` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps are key-value pairs.

Keys must be unique.

If you use the same key, you overwrite the old value. If you would print the map after the first 2 lines, it would print these values.

```
testMap['dn'] = 'test name1';
testMap['ph'] = '4160000000';

print(testMap); // prints test name1 & 4160000000
```

Then later you overwrite the values, so you get the new values when you print the map.

You can try to have a List that has maps:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = [];
```

Then add maps to it:

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new Map();
testMap['dn'] = 'test name1';
testMap['ph'] = '4160000000';

list.add(testMap);

print(list);
```

Comment: Are you saying that in my case I shouldn't be using a map to get an output like I mentioned on my comment above?

Comment: Is this the best way to go about this? Declaring two variables for one thing?

Comment: Would make more sense if you create a data class and work with objects: `class Data{String dn; String ph;}` then `List<Data> list = []; list.add(Data('test name1', '4160000000'))' etc. Don't forget to create toString() method.

Comment: Thanks, I liked this way more than the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of the map must unique, values can be the same. So you repeated the keys twice. This replaces the old values ​​with the new.
change code like this

```
 void initState() {
super.initState();
testMap['dn'] = 'test name1';
testMap['ph'] = '4160000000';
testMap['dn1'] = 'test name2';
testMap['ph1'] = '7780000000';
```

}